# pip install -e . went through but conf.json not found

Tags: python

I read a number of guides on how to pack a project (for example [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), [here](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html), [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/goodpractices.html), etc.) and the `pip install -e .` went through fine.

Nevertheless, when I open an `IPython` console and run `import myPackage as mypkg` I got a `path` error related to a `.json` file, but let me explain better.

I have setup my project according to [this](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure) layout.
I have created the following `conf.json` file

```
{
    "num_decimals":3,
    "color_map" : "tab10"
}
```

and the following `config.py` file

```
import json

data = json.load(open(file="./conf.json", encoding="utf-8"))

NUM_DECIMALS = data["num_decimals"]
COLORMAP = data["color_map"]
```

The error that I get when I run `import myPackage as mypkg` on an `IPython` console is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './conf.json'
```

and I have no idea how to fix it.
If it may be useful I am running on `Windows 10` and I am using `Anaconda 2.2.0 64 bit` that has `Python 3.9.12` and `IPython 8.4.0.`
Any hint is more than welcome and if you need more info just ask.

Comment: Linked layout page has no JSON files being used... perhaps you should just use `conf.py` rather than needing to parse any file? E.g. `data = {"num_decimals": 3}; NUM_DECIMALS = data["num_decimals"]`, then you can `import data, NUM_DECIMALS from myPackage.conf`

Comment: Is the file `conf.json` supposed to be inside the package `myPackage` or in the directory where you are importing `myPackage`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think it is suggested to parse data rather than having configurations in a .py file. Among other methods (.ini, .yaml, ...,  files for example) I went the .json route as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/UU7cb1qiS64

Comment: Regardless, when you use `import`, it just runs the code line-by-line as if it were in your main module (or terminal session)... Therefore, `open('./conf.json')` will look for files in the same directory where you started IPython and not within the package that had been installed.

Comment: Linked video has nothing to do with external library installation/packaging, so seems you are confusing multiple concepts

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think I pertinently replied to your post:  you claimed that I should use conf.py and A) I answered that it is not suggested ( I could even interpret your answer  as a deliberate attempt to push a StackOverflow user, namely me, off the track; B) I added the video as supporting information that among other methods to use an external configuration file - as it is suggested to be - I choose the .json file route. So it is very pertinent to the issue that I exposed and the points that you made.

Comment: There's two separate things. As mentioned also by Vishnu, the file is trying to be found in the local file path to the console. But if you want to store config constants within a Python package, then, yes a direct variable in a `.py` file would be the preferred way to do that.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can you document that including config constants in a .py file would be the preferred way? Because that is quite confusing as it is suggested to keep config and code separated. So you may be, once more, wrong. Perhaps a way is to include the file in the MANIFEST file, but there may be other ways that I am going to investigate.

Comment: You're already using a `config.py` file. Therefore you're already doing what I'm saying. I'm only suggesting that you don't use a level of redirection and just put the variables as literals in that file rather than reading any files into dictionaries then extracting them from the same dict.

Comment: @VishnuNadhan good question. My final goal is that once the user install the package, then a “default” conf.json file is also installed. Such a conf.json file can be then edited according to user preferences.